# Too many redirects error with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


    Redirect /p-contact-us http://www.example.com/contact/
    Redirect /p-our-services http://www.example.com/services/
    Redirect /white_papers http://www.example.com/insights/
    Redirect /case_studies http://www.example.com/insights/
    Redirect /blog http://www.example.com/news-events/
    Redirect /press_releases http://www.example.com/news-events/
    Redirect /white_papers.php http://www.example.com/insights/
    Redirect /p-services http://www.example.com/services/
    Redirect /p-industry-experience http://www.example.com/about/
    Redirect /p-thought-leadership http://www.example.com/about/leadership-team/
    Redirect /press_releases.php http://www.example.com/news-events/
    Redirect /p-about http://www.example.com/about/
    Redirect /p-careers http://www.example.com/careers/
    Redirect /p-merger-integration http://www.example.com/services/management-consulting/merger-integration/
    Redirect /p-organizational-development http://www.example.com/services/management-consulting/organizational-development/
    Redirect /p-value-assurance http://www.example.com/services/management-consulting/value-assurance/
    Redirect /p-business-continuity-compliance2 http://www.example.com/services/management-consulting/business-continuity-compliance/
    Redirect /p-it-strategy-governance http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/it-strategy-governance/
    Redirect /p-outsourcing-advisory-services http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/outsourcing-advisory-vendor-management/
    Redirect /p-benchmarking-analysis http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/benchmarking-analysis/
    Redirect /p-it-operations-management http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/it-operations-management-itil/
    Redirect /p-it-portfolio-management http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/it-portfolio-management/
    Redirect /p-application-and-erp-strategy http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/application-and-erp-strategy/
    Redirect /p-program-and-project-management2 http://www.example.com/services/project-leadership/project-program-management/
    Redirect /p-business-decision-analytics http://www.example.com/services/project-leadership/business-analysis-requirements/
    Redirect /p-change-management-and-communication http://www.example.com/services/management-consulting/
    Redirect /p-technical-subject-matter-expert http://www.example.com/services/it-strategic-services/
    Redirect /p-major-capital-projects-(mcp) http://www.example.com/services/project-leadership/major-capital-projects-mcp/
    Redirect /p-information-management-strategy http://www.example.com/services/analytics-information-management/information-strategy-architecture/
    Redirect /p-data-management-governance http://www.example.com/services/analytics-information-management/data-governance/
    Redirect /p-about-us http://www.example.com/about/
    Redirect /p-jonas-georgsson http://www.example.com/about/leadership-team/
    Redirect /p-dhiren-shethia http://www.example.com/about/leadership-team/
    Redirect /p-rick-snell http://www.example.com/about/leadership-team/
    </IfModule>

    # Block WordPress xmlrpc.php requests
    <Files xmlrpc.php>
    deny from all
    </Files>

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Here I am getting "too many ridects" issue for only few pages starting with news-events and the url is becoming like

```
http://www.example.com/news-events//2018/07/12/erp-on-cloud-a-new-approach-to-selecting-a-cloud-erp-in-the-digital-age-blog/
```

How can I fix this? I have even tried by removing '/' from news-events/ above but still getting the same error. I have cleared cookies, cache etc but no use. Everything was working fine before but suddenly few pages stopped loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a WordPress problem or error, but is an issue related to the configuration of your web server or hosting provider. If you do encounter such error, you can solve the issue by adding 1 line to the WordPress root .htaccess file. Follow the below step by step procedure to solve such issue:

1. Connect to your WordPress website using FTP.
2. Download the .htaccess file from the root of your WordPress website.
3. Add the below line before the WordPress rules (above the # BEGIN WordPress line)

   ErrorDocument 401 default

Answer reference : [wpwhitesecurity.com](https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-tips-webmasters/fix-too-many-redirects-error-wordpress/)